# c++ exit loop based on keyboard input

Tags: c++, loops

Is it possible to exit a C++ loop based on keyboard input without actually having to input something each iteration?

For instance

```
while(checkkeyboardinput != 'q')
   {
     do work
   }
```

I feel that this is very easy, but google isn't helping me, and I can't remember how to do this. Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I'm using VS2008

Comment: Which platform are you using? Winodows, Linux, Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try _kbhit(). As far as I know it checks if there is any keyboard input waiting in the buffer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c%28VS.80%29.aspx

> _kbhit
>
> Checks the console for keyboard input.
>
> int _kbhit( void );
>
> **Return Value**
>
> _kbhit returns a nonzero value if a key has been pressed. Otherwise, it
>   returns 0.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The _kbhit function checks the console
>   for a recent keystroke. If the
>   function returns a nonzero value, a
>   keystroke is waiting in the buffer.
>   The program can then call _getch or
>   _getche to get the keystroke.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ncurses, you can, very easily, with `getch()`. However, there is not standard way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You neglected to mention what OS you're running.  Getting keyboard input is OS dependent (even library dependent -- eg. how to do it with GTK is obviously GTK specific.)

Well, GTK runs on multiple OS'es, so... but you get the idea.  You need to specify a bit more about the environment your working in to get a reasonable answer.